# Appending polygons in R using sf

Tags: r, sf

I'm trying to create a multipolygon dataset where each row is identifiable.

Example below

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

# example raster data
r <- brick(nl = 2, nrows = 5, ncols = 10)
set.seed(54); r[] <- rpois(ncell(r)*nlayers(r), lambda = 3)
names(r) <- c("layer_1", "layer_2")
r

for (i in 1:nlayers(r)) {
  s <- r[[i]]
  # set values below x to NA, all else to 1
  s[s[] < quantile(r[[i]], 0.9)] <- NA
  s[!is.na(s[])] <- 1
  # convert from raster to multipolygon
  s <- st_union(as(rasterToPolygons(s, na.rm = TRUE), "sf"))
  # send to workspace
  ## ideally here I could bind to an existing empty dataset
  ## after naming to rows
  assign(x = paste0("poly", i), value = s)
}
# no way to tell which one is poly1 or poly2?
poly3 <- c(
  st_cast(poly1, "GEOMETRY"),
  st_cast(poly2, "GEOMETRY"))
poly3
names(poly3) <- names(r)
names(poly3)
write_sf(poly3, "./test_poly_output.shp") ## works
rownames(poly3) <- names(r) ## error
poly3$name <- names(r)
poly3
write_sf(poly3, "./test_poly_output_2.shp") ## error
```

I want to be able to open the dataset in QGIS or Arc, and see which rows correspond to the appropriate layer. Opening the `test_poly_output.shp` shows the following which isn't particularly helpful, even though in this example `FID_1` == 0 obviously corresponds with layer 1
[image]

Ideally I would be able to bind to an existing empty `sfc` class. The code below works for a `MULTILINESTRING`, but I cannot get it to work for `MULTIPOLYGON` or `GEOMETRY` types.

```
## Example where LINESTRINGS can be appended to blank sfc
rConts <- st_sf(st_sfc(crs = 4326))

for (i in 1:nlayers(r)) {
  contsR <- r[[i]]
  contsR <- rasterToContour(r[[i]], levels = quantile(r[[i]], 0.9))
  names(contsR) <- "Q90"
  contsR <- as(contsR, "sf")
  rownames(contsR) <- gsub("X_", "", names(r[[i]]))
  contsR$Year <- as.integer(gsub("layer_", "", names(r[[i]])))
  rConts <- rbind(rConts, contsR)
}
rConts
write_sf(rConts, "./test_contourLines_output.shp")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminology is  bit unclear but I think it boils down to you trying to save spatial features *vectors* and expecting each element to have some attributes. You can't do that with vectors, you have to make spatial features *data frames*.

If you have an object that is an `sfc` class:

```
> class(poly3)
[1] "sfc_GEOMETRY" "sfc"
```

then saving it as a Shapefile will only save the geometry. To add extra information to each element of that geometry vector, create a spatial features *data frame*:

```
> sp3 = st_as_sf(data.frame(name=names(r), geometry=poly3))
> sp3
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -180 ymin: -90 xmax: 180 ymax: 90
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
     name                       geometry
1 layer_1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-180 18, -1...
2 layer_2 MULTIPOLYGON (((144 -54, 18...
```

Saving that to a Shapefile and loading into a GIS should give you a `name` column with the name in.